# How to pass data from a collection view header to collection view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, header

I have a collection view with a header and a body.

The header has a button that increases the date by 1 month.

I need the button in the header to also increase the date in the body of the collection view.

Here is the basic code:

```
class ExampleViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.refresh), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "dateUpdated"), object: nil)

        }
                
        @objc private func refresh() {
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ExampleCell", for: indexPath) as! ExampleCell
        
        cell.configureCell(with: indexPath)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "ExampleHeader", for: indexPath) as! ExampleHeader
        
        header.configureHeader()

        return header
    }
    
}
```

```
class ExampleHeader: UICollectionReusableView {
    
    var selectedDate = Date()
    
    func configureHeader() {
        //Configure stuff
    }
    
    @IBAction func addMonthButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        selectedDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: selectedDate)!
        
        //Tell the ExampleCell class to add a month to its selectedDate property.
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "dateUpdated"), object: nil)
    }
    }
```

```
class ExampleCell: UICollectionViewCell {
        
        var selectedDate = Date()
        
        func configureCell(with indexPath: IndexPath) {
            //Configure stuff
        }
        
        
}
```

Do I use a delegate/protocol method to get the data across?

```
protocol DateSwitcherDelegate {
    func switchDate(with date: Date)
}

class ExampleHeader: UICollectionReusableView {

    var dateSwitcherDelegate: DateSwitcherDelegate!

@IBAction func leftButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        selectedDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: selectedDate)!

        dateSwitcherDelegate.switchDate(with: selectedDate)

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "dateUpdated"), object: nil)
    }
}
```

```
extension ExampleCell: DateSwitcherDelegate {
    
    func switchDate(with date: Date) {
        selectedDate = date
    }
    
}
```

I attempted this, but received:
"Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file"

Am I going about this correctly? Or should I be using the ExampleViewController class to pass the data?

I am new to programming and this is my first project.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit: I'm working on creating a model for the date, as suggested by @VadimBelyaev. Here's what I have so far.

```
import Foundation

class MonthToAdjust {
    
    var date = Date()
    
    init(date: Date) {
        self.date = date
    }
    
    func increaseDateByAMonth() {
        date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: date)!
    }
    func decreaseDateByAMonth() {
        date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: date)!
    }
    
}
```

How do I access the variable in the ViewController? How do I update the date in the model? Thanks.

Comment: Good start and congrats with the first project! I'm afraid you're trying to solve the wrong problem. The two views exchanging data may lead to unmaintainable code. Consider having a single model object that will communicate with the two views. Pass a reference to your model to both of the views and they will ask the model to update in reaction to user actions. Use the Delegate pattern instead of notifications to let the views react to model changes. Avoid putting any business logic in the views (like increasing a date by one month - things like that better be in the model). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help @VadimBelyaev! Could you provide a sample of code to describe what you're talking about? It sounds like I need to create another class with a date variable?